# Azure VM SQL Server Access

Tags: sql-server, azure

I provisioned an Azure SQL Server VM instance (image: Free SQL Server License: SQL Server 2017 Developer on Windows Server 2016) using my Windows Account.

As part of the setup process I also created a `server admin (VM_Admin)` account for the VM.  I can log into the VM using Remote Desktop with VM_Admin and and can start/stop SQL Server services, but then can't log into the SQL Server through SSMS (`Error:Login failed for user 'ServerName\VM_Admin'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)`)

I also have the Microsoft account that I used to set up the Azure VM in the first place, but that account can't connect to the VM at all through Remote Desktop (`Error: The credentials that were used to connect to --IP Address-- don't work.  Please use new credentials.`)

So... I have one account that can connect to the VM but not SSMS, and another that can't connect at all.  What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generic message "Login Failed for User (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)" means you entered invalid credentials when logging into SQL Server.

You need to figure out what user does have rights to SQL server.  Usually this is the user that you logged in with when you installed SQL Server or the user that is the default administrator on the computer.  To get a list of users on the machine.

For more details refer: [How to Fix Login Failed for User (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456) Step-By-Step – Add SQL Administrator to SQL Management Studio](http://itproguru.com/expert/2014/09/how-to-fix-login-failed-for-user-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456-step-by-step-add-sql-administrator-to-sql-management-studio/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: It appears that somehow Azure managed to misspell the username when setting up SQL Server.  I had to connect remotely through SSMS on another computer and then change the username of the admin.  Really odd behavior.  Thanks for the response.